# How can I navigate into tab from normal window?

Tags: button, tabs, titanium, event-listener

I build a simple application by using Titanium Studio.
From normal window, when I click a button it must go back to the tab view and activate the third tab but now it show the full screen window of that third tab instead. What should I do ?

This is my ApplicationTabGroup.js

```
function ApplicationTabGroup(Window) {

//create module instance
var self = Ti.UI.createTabGroup(),
    MapWindow = require('ui/common/MapTab'),
    ListWindow = require('ui/common/ListTab'),
    ContactWindow = require('/ui/common/ContactTab');

//create app tabs
var win1 = new MapWindow('MapTab'),
    win2 = new ListWindow('ListTab')
    win3 = new ContactWindow('Contact')

//Tab1
var tab1 = Ti.UI.createTab({
    //title: 'MapTab',
    icon: '/images/icmapactive.png',
    window: win1
});
win1.containingTab = tab1;


//Tab2
var tab2 = Ti.UI.createTab({
    //title: 'ListTab',
    icon: '/images/iclistactive.png',
    window: win2
});
win2.containingTab = tab2;

//Tab3
var tab3 = Ti.UI.createTab({
    //title: 'Contact',
    icon: '/images/icmailactive.png',
    window: win3
});
win3.containingTab = tab3;

self.addTab(tab1);
self.addTab(tab2);
self.addTab(tab3);

    return self;
};
module.exports = ApplicationTabGroup;
```

And this is my button's eventListener. It is in normal window.

```
btInfo.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var ContactTab = require('/ui/common/ContactTab');
    new ContactTab(Window).open();
});
```

Many thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [setActiveTab](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup-method-setActiveTab) function. In your eventlistener, create ApplicationTabGroup and set the contact tab to be active. You can use object or tab index as parameter.